# How to Check if AWS Named Configure profile exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-config

How do I check if a named profile exists before I attempt to use it ?

`aws cli` will throw an ugly error if I attempt to use a non-existent profile, so I'd like to do something like this :

```
  $(awsConfigurationExists "${profile_name}") && aws iam list-users --profile "${profile_name}" || echo "can't do it!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1 - Check entries in the `.aws/config` file

```
function awsConfigurationExists() {

    local profile_name="${1}"
    local profile_name_check=$(cat $HOME/.aws/config | grep "\[profile ${profile_name}]")

    if [ -z "${profile_name_check}" ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi

}
```

### Method 2 - Check results of aws configure list ,  see [aws-cli issue #819](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/819#issuecomment-683414098)

```
function awsConfigurationExists() {


    local profile_name="${1}"
    local profile_status=$( (aws configure --profile ${1} list) 2>&1)

    if [[ $profile_status = *'could not be found'* ]]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi

}
```

---

### usage

---

```
$(awsConfigurationExists "my-aws-profile") && echo "does exist" || echo "does not exist"
```

**or**

```
if $(awsConfigurationExists "my-aws-profile"); then
    echo "does exist"
  else
    echo "does not exist"
  fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same problem and the proposed answer did not work for me.

Here is my solution with `aws-cli/2.8.5 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/21.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off`:

```bash
export AWS_PROFILE=localstack
aws configure list-profiles | grep -q "${AWS_PROFILE}"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "AWS Profile [$AWS_PROFILE] already exists"
else
  echo "Creating AWS Profile [$AWS_PROFILE]"
  aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE set aws_access_key_id test
  aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE set aws_secret_access_key test
fi
```